# How to import a Python class from a directory which has dependency in the same directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I want to use a class `A`, which is in a subdirectory `dir` in file `A.py`. It has dependency with file `B.py` which is also in the same directory `dir`. I want to use the `A` class from its parent directory. The file tree looks like this:

```
parent_dir/
    dir/
        __init__.py (empty file)
        A.py (imports B)
        B.py
    C.py <-- I am here
```

Content of A:

```py
from B import B

class A:
  def __init__():
    pass
```

And contents of B:

```py
class B:
  def __init__():
    pass
```

Now when I try to import `A.py` from `C.py` by `from dir.A import A`, I get:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 from stargan_v2_tensorflow.networks import Generator

File ~/parent_dir/C.py:1
---> 1 from B import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'B'
```

I tried importing `B.py` by `import dir.B as B` and `from dir import B` so that it finds `B`, but still I get the same error. How can I import `A` with its dependency?

Comment: Did you place the `__init__.py` inside `dir`?

Comment: …if you did, it would be `from dir.B import *`.

Comment: Yes I did, and the errors I get are after that. I also tried `from dir.B import *`, still `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: It is `from .B import B`, note the `.` before `B`, that's a relative import.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Comment: No, I don't want to change files in dir

Answer (score 0):

It is `from .B import B`, note the `.` before `B`, that's a relative import.

Maybe take a look at the ["Relative imports for the billionth time"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) Stack Overflow post.

Reproduce:

```bash
mkdir -p dir
printf '' > dir/__init__.py
printf 'class B: pass' > dir/B.py
printf 'from .B import B\nclass A: pass' > dir/A.py
printf 'from dir.A import A\nprint("SUCCESS")' > C.py
python C.py
```

Comment: Is there any way to achieve this without changing import statements in `dir`?

Comment: You could add `sys.path.insert(1, str(Path(__file__).parent / "dir"))` in `C.py`, but bad practice, why would you want to do that?